# jQuery hide() does not hide parent

Tags: jquery, forms, html, hide

JQuery still driving me mad...
Here's the problem: I have a page where visitors can leave their email address by clicking on a link inside a div (id="contact").

```
<div id="contact"><a href="">vuoi lasciare un recapito?</a></div>
```

Once clicked, the "contact" div loads a php form. The user types in his email address, then the address is checked, then inserted in the Database, etc... Usual business.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contact a').click(function()
    {
    $('#contact').load('mailform.php');
    return false;
    });
$('#contact').submit(function(){
    var email = $('input[name=email]', '#submitmail').val();
    var submit = $('input[name=submit]', '#submitmail').val();
    $('#contact').load('mailform.php',{'email': email,'submit': submit});
    return false;
    });
//the close button - start
$(".cls").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().html());
    $(this).parent().hide();
    });
//the close button - end
});
```

The pain comes when I want to add a "close" button or link, so the user can hide the form after or even before filling the form.

```
<div id="submitmail">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <p><label for="email"><?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?></label><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="inserisci" /></p>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
</div>
<span class="cls">Chiudi</span>
```

The link (and the "the close button" script) simply don't work. No alerts, no switches, no div disappearing... Nothing.
Already tried `$('span.cls').click(function()` and `$('#cls').click(function()` (after switching the "span" with a "div" and the class with an ID) no clues. Just a link to click that does nothing. Firebug and IE dev toolbar don't even get into the function.
Alternative solutions are welcome...

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's working as static html: http://jsfiddle.net/F9TLD/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#contact").on("click", ".cls", function(){
    alert($(this).parent().html());
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

since the `.cls` element does not exists at the time of binding - so you need to delegate the handler to a suitable parent element. Read the "direct and delegated events" section of this:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Excerpt from above link:

> If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and
>   attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or,
>   use delegated events to attach an event handler...

Comment: I think you're right: actually the .cls element in not part of the "original" DOM. Unfortunately it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: Wait up...which version of jQuery are you using? We'll get this working, don't worry.

Comment: script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js". That's the version. Should I use the latest? EDIT: I'm trying with 1.7, I'll let you know ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the close button is not part of the DOM on documentReady.

Answer (score 0):

You did not copied here the parent of the following html:

```
<span class="cls">Chiudi</span>
```

Try this:

```
$(".cls").click(function(){
    // alert($(this).parent().html());
    $('#submitmail').hide();
});
```